# How to Animate the background world map position

Tags: jquery, background, position, jquery-animate

I want to make something similar to http://www.impala-wl.com/our_global_locations.aspx . M
My code is attached below, but the background image is repeating and my animation is not getting to the specific country. Its just animating. How can i make the animation go to certain country div. I want  an animation somewhat similar like in the example link given above, ie. When i click on a certain country div, a popup should show, (that i can handle). Im stuck with the animation and the background world map animation.

Can someone please help me out here. Im stuck trying this for 4 days. Im not expert in Jquery. Would really appreciate if someone point me out steps/ways to figure this out.

Thank you so much for your time.

My code is here:
http://www.mediafire.com/?pwmf4ywi9r63i73

Answer (score 0):

I think that if you want do it with jQuery, you should set this image as a background of some div (set its id to #map). Then you must create js code which will move background.

You can use this code [link](http://ld.kacperkolodziej.com/?brush=js&code=./js/gesty_myszy/gesty.js) (demo: [link](http://kacperkolodziej.com/demo/js/gesty_myszy))

In your code you must change background position

Next time if you want to help, put your code into pastebin or sth else.

Comment: Thanks, @KacperKolodziej let me try with the code and i'll update here.

Comment: OK. I can tell you that sb created plugin for jQuery which allows to use background-position property in $.animate() method :)

Comment: its not working :( can you please show me a simple working demo.

Comment: It's not working, because it's example. I'll create other, but you must be patient.

Comment: I did sth, but it doesn't work well. I think it's a problem of browser limits for javascript. You can see demo here: [link](http://kacperkolodziej.com/demo/jquery/moving_background/) and javascript code here: [link](http://ld.kacperkolodziej.com/?brush=js&code=./codes/js/jquery/moving_background/moving.js) (index.html: [link](http://ld.kacperkolodziej.com/?brush=xml&code=./codes/js/jquery/moving_background/index.html)) I think that javascript isn't good solution to do scripts like this. This solutions works in Chrome better then in Firefox. I don't know if it works in IE cause I'm Linux user.